# Can't disable caching

Tags: magento2, cache

Trying to disable all cache types in Magento 2 from **System > Tools > Cache Management**.

But all I get is the following error:

> Deployment config file env.php is not writable.

I tried making app/etc/env.php writable (777) but still no luck.

Comment: any update? also facing the same issue even with change of  app/etc/env.php writable

Comment: Even with both config.php and env.php set to writable, it's still giving me that error..

Answer (score 6):

First of all connect to your web server with your telnet software.

Change directory with `cd <magento dir>/app/etc`

Type `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento/app/etc` to change mode for `env.php` file to be writable.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 app/etc/env.php
```

I hope this helps you !!

Comment: Should never use 777 in production, read up on it.

Answer (score 3):

I too had the same issue in Magento 2.1.2  with message being returned as "Deployment config file env.php is not writable.". 
But it got **resolved** when I additionally set the write permission for **app/etc/config.php** apart from the **env.php** file